# elasticsearch predective search solution

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Trying to get predictive drop down search ,How can i make search always starts from left to right 
like in example   "I_kimchy park"  , "park"
If i search only "par"  i have to get only park in return , but here i am getting both words , how to treat empty space as a character

```
POST /test1
{
  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "autocomplete":{
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer":"standard",
          "filter":[ "standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", "edgeNgram" ,"whitespace"]
        }
      },
      "filter":{
        "ngram":{
          "type":"edgeNgram",
          "min_gram":2,
          "max_gram":15,
          "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}




PUT /test1/tweet/_mapping
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "user": {"type":"string", "index_analyzer" : "autocomplete","search_analyzer" : "autocomplete"}
        }
    }}


POST /test1/tweet/1
{"user" : "I_kimchy park"}


POST /test1/tweet/3
{  "user" : "park"}



GET /test1/tweet/_search
{
 "query": {
   "match_phrase_prefix": {
     "user": "park"
   }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because your `standard` tokenizer splits your `user` field by white spaces. You can use [Keyword Tokenizer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html#analysis-keyword-tokenizer) in order to treat whole string as a single value (single token).

Please keep in mind that this change may affect other of your functionalities that use this field. You may have to add dedicated "not tokenized" `user` field for this purpose.